# Getting formatted Youtube Description (With line breaks and hyperlinks)

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, youtube

I'm wondering how I can pull a YouTube description from a given video whilst maintaining the formatting. I have successfully managed to get the description/title/thumbnail of the video, I just can't seem to keep the HTML formatting in the description. Whenever I put it into a div, it becomes one big clump of plain text.

My Code is as follows:

```
 var json = (function () {
     var json = null;
     $.ajax({
         'async': false,
         'global': false,
         'url': youTubeURL,
         'dataType': "json",
         'success': function (data) {
             json = data;
         }
     });
     return json;
 })();
```

Afterwards, I get the description and title like this:

```
 var desc = json.entry.media$group.media$description.$t;
 var title = json.entry.title.$t;
```

This is all well and good. However, when I go to put it in a div, like this:

```
 $('#video_desc').html('<h1>' + title + '</h1><p>' + desc + '</p>');
```

The description then shows up as one big block of text, where there should be line breaks and links. The weird thing is that when I do an alert or console.log of the description, it shows the correct formatting...

I'm sure it's something small I'm missing, but any help would be great, cheers!

Comment: whats an example of a `youTubeURL`?

Comment: @jmore009  `var youTubeURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + $(this).data('src') + '?v=2&alt=json';`

Comment: can you give me an example of `$(this).data('src')` as well? one that is not working for you?

Comment: @jmore009 Well it would be the unique part of a video link like 'YftTq4XXTg'. I have a bunch of them stored in a database, which I pull from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the line formatting, you can use:

```
p{
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

That will keep the formatting, but the rest is coming in as a string (call `$.type(var)` to see) so the links and any other HTML formatting would not carry over. My suggestion would be to find and replace the links for actual clickable ones. You can look into a [URL](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/url.js) library to help with this.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kwo2rjmn/)

Comment: Thanks for that, the CSS fix did the trick! I'll now get to work on the link formatting.